# Is there any rule when replacing apostrophe intead of some letters?

Tags: word-usage, apostrophe

In some English songs I found words like:

- *nothin'*
- *'em*
- *gon'*
- *'bout*

Are there any rules to make words like these? Are the words formal? Are there other examples?

Comment: These dropped letters of variations on spelling are based on actual everyday speech (common, not formal), and are too numerous to list here. You can find a few [here](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/contractions-informal.htm)

Answer (score 1):

These words are based upon pronunciations. When you speak them, you make such sound. E.g., when you want to say 'something', it may sound like 'somethin". 
They are not formal. They are usually used, as you said, in songs or conversations in novels.